# Wifi not working after installation

Tags: release-loki, wifi

I'm new to Linux so please bear with me.

I've just installed 0.4.1 Loki from a USB drive and whereas the WiFi worked when I booted up from the USB drive, it doesn't after full installation.

If I go into `System Settings > Network`, it doesn't show any WiFi networks in the left hand column. However, if I click on `Edit Connections`, my network appears in the drop down box. But I can't seem to activate it in any way.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

Inside [app-center](/questions/tagged/app-center) It will be a [kernel](/questions/tagged/kernel) update (`bcmwl-kernel-source`). Simply click on **free** button to start the Broadcom 802.11 Linux STA wireless driver update.
Done, everything working fine after this.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with a MacBook Pro late 2008.

I had to install the firmware driver for the broadcom network-adapter manually. I found it out, because the `dmesg` command gave me the reason and the install guide of elementary OS points to the same issue.

To install without a network connection I mounted the install media and followed the instructions for the bcmwl-kernel-source [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/bcm43xx#b43%20-%20No%20Internet%20access).

Finally it works.